# Make flex container restricted by window height

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a web app that takes up the entire window and uses its own internal scrolling mechanism.  I do not want any content to be outside of the browser window.

Right now I am trying to use a layout that incorporates a flex container, set to flex columns, that has a fixed header navbar, and then a content area that will display dynamic data that will have a scrollbar to view content overflow.  This way the second header will always be on the page.  I am using Angular to do this, and because the component being routed in adds another level to the DOM before the header and content `div`s, the flex container does not restrict their height.

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 1 1 50px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dynamic-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.item {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>

  <div class="header">
    Head
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    
    <app-component _nghost class="ng-star-inserted">
      <div class="header">SubHeader</div>
    
      <div class='dynamic-content'>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>      
      </div>
    </app-component>
  
    
    
  </div>
```

I want the `div.container` to only take up the remaining height of the page, and the `div.dynamic-content` to not resize as items are added past its bottom bound, and instead cut off any overflow and display a scrollbar to get to the rest of the content. That way both the SubHeader `div` and the main Head `div` will always be on screen as the user scrolls down the page.

The `angular-router-endpoint` and `angular-routed-component` `div`s are as their classes describe, an Angular Router-Outlet and a custom Angular Component inserted by the Outlet.  The component cannot be styled directly, as far as I am aware of.

Comment: If you want to restrict it by viewport height, just use `max-height: 100vh`

Comment: @Terry that does work perfectly for this example, I believe I oversimplified.  I am using angular, and the DOM is slightly different.  I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I believe I had and below you can see a solution to your problem.

#### Key part

Key thing here is to add `height: 100vh` to `.page`, so it won't grow over viewpoint's height.

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 1 1 50px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dynamic-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.item {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>

  <div class="header">
    Head
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">SubHeader</div>

    <div class='dynamic-content'>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Your answer did work for the example I provided, but not in the case of my actual app.  The app is using angular, and routed components, and I think the issue is actually with the way that Angular insert DOM objects at router endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue and found that it was not a CSS issue, but something I had misunderstood about the way that angular router structures the DOM.

The component tag that was inserted had to have `display: flex` set.  The way to add styles to the component's tag directly is to use the CSS selector: `:host` and in my case I had to use `:host { display: flex }` to get this to work properly.

I asked my initial question thinking the issue was with my CSS, and have edited it to match my specific issue

Comment: It is a CSS issue, Cascaded Style Sheet, where cascade is broken at the level where your component shows up unstyled :) . you had to style it and include it into your flexbox layout ....

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to understand the expected result.

Within your code you inbricate flexboxes, **but forget the wrapper** `.angular-routed-component`, and you are loosing from here the benefit of the flex model.

I have removed and updated some values. (no `max-height` but only `height`, and `flex` reduce to one value enough to make it fill the remaining space.*(`flex:1;`)* , added also some `overflow:hidden`, to trigger later the scroll)

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;/* update */
  overflow:hidden;/* update */
}

body {/* update */
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  min-height: 50px;/* update, no flex rules */
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.container, .angular-routed-component {/* here same rules for the angular child compoment */
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;/* update */
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;/* update */
}

.dynamic-content {
  flex: 1;/* update */
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.item {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>

  <div class="header">
    Head
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="angular-router-endpoint"></div>
    <div class="angular-routed-component">
      <div class="header">SubHeader</div>

      <div class='dynamic-content'>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
        <div class="item">item</div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
```

Comment: the issue is that the `.angular-routed-component` is an angular inserted component and you cannot apply styles directly to that dom element.

Comment: @MasonTurvey Are you sure about that ? once it is in the dom of the document, css from the style will be apply to it as soon as the class name matches, else, you either have the wrong classname or angular overwrites the styles. If it does overwrite the rules, 2 option i think of : a) increase the weight of the selector  b) or once angular scripts are loaded, update the style for that element via javascript. I would avoid `!important` to keep it clean. best would be to use an `id` for that element if it does have one. if it doesn't, add it on the fly and let CSS in the stylesheet.

Comment: Increasing weight may work as well, but I found that the most direct way to apply the style directly to the component is to use angulars :host selector

Comment: @MasonTurvey whatever method you use,  the thing is to include this component into your flexbox layout, you have no choice if you want the cascade to work ;)